# AWS Security Groups - EC2 to RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I wanted to ask about connecting EC2 to RDP in AWS.

I have added my EC2 Security Group (that contains the EC2 instances) into the Default RDP Group and Data is flowing - the connection works.

The EC2 Security group has Port 80 to 0.0.0.0/0 and SSH to my IP enabled.

I'm a touch concerned that by adding this EC2 group to the RDS Database it will allow Port 80 traffic from anywhere to access the Databases. Is this correct or wrong?

Do the rules in the EC2 apply to the RDS instances if you connect them like this?

I did read on the AWS websites that 'Database Security Groups only allow access to the database server port'. Can anyone confirm this is correct?

thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your RDS security groups are different then your EC2 security groups.

So what you did is you set a EC2 security group to have access to that RDS security group. So any server you setup with that EC2 group can hit the database port for any RDS instance that is in the RDS security group.

So public traffic can't hit the database port, on the instances in the ec2 security group can.